# OpenShift Python mongoDB environment variables not set / can't connect

Tags: python, mongodb, openshift

This is in my application file head:

```
import os
import sys
from cgi import parse_qs, escape
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

I have the mongoDB 2.4 gear installed, and am trying to connect via

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/')
```

I get the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/openshift/531b77fd500446980900010d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 239, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/531b77fd500446980900010d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 269, in parse_uri
    nodes = split_hosts(hosts, default_port=default_port)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/531b77fd500446980900010d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 209, in split_hosts
    nodes.append(parse_host(entity, port))
  File "/var/lib/openshift/531b77fd500446980900010d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 137, in parse_host
    raise ConfigurationError("Port number must be an integer.")
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Port number must be an integer.
```

looks like `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT` isn't set

```
print  OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT --> NameError: name 'OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT' is not defined
```

Same with `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST`

What would I need to do, to set up a connection?

Update:

I was able to connect directly via client by hardcoding info from rockmongo

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:password@[ip addr]:[port]/')
```

but when I do

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb:admin:password@%s:%s/' %  os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST'], os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT']))
```

I get

```
[error] (<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError('OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST',), <traceback object at 0x7f7bc8367248>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenShift connection variables are defined as environment variables, they cannot be accessed as normal Python variables. So the print statement you gave does not work, the following should;

```
import os
print os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT']
```

You should change your code to;

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb:%s:%s/' % (os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST'], os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT))
```

You can refer to an example [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-twt-mongo-demo/blob/master/wsgi/twtapp.py#L12).

Comment: I updated my main question with attempt success/issue details