# how to use MongoHQ database in openshift app

Tags: python, ruby, openshift, pymongo, mongohq

At first I tried:

```
import pymongo
MONGOHQ_URL = "mongodb://username:password@kahana.mongohq.com:10025/dbname"
conn = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGOHQ_URL)
```

but apparently it failed and it throws following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 95, in <module>
    conn = pymongo.Connection(MONGOHQ_URL)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53abb500028e/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 236, in __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53abb500028e/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 369, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

They have an example, but it's in Ruby and I have no idea. If I am not wrong, I guess the connection is happening in [this](https://github.com/MongoHQ/mongohq-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/quick_start.rb) script.

Can anyone makeout from this ruby code and help me so that I can use in my python script with pymongo? I have already set environment variable `MONGO_URL`

Comment: You'll want to check out the answer provided in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274745/openshift-python-mongodb-environment-variables-not-set-cant-connect

Comment: @niharvey its different, he is asking how to connect to MongoDB which is provided by Open Shift, not mongo hq.

Comment: Can you share more of your code as well as the URI that (I assume) you are assigning to your MONGOHQ_URL? If you are seeing a permissions error, it could be incorrect auth being passed or attempting to access the wrong database.